# Inserting numbers with sed in Linux?

Tags: sed

I have the following line in cmdline

```
sed -e '1s/^/\\documentstyle\[11pt\]\{article\}\n/' -e 's/[0-9]//g' test.txt
```

My desired output is something like this

```
\documentstyle[11pt]{article}
rest of the file
```

However I only get this

```
\documentstyle[pt]{article}
rest of the file
```

I can't seem to find a way to insert numbers. I tried backslashing. Solution might be simple, but I'm a newbie with sed.

Comment: Your second substitute command removes the numbers you added in the first.  So, what is the second (`s/[0-9]//g`) operation intended to do?

Comment: Oh wow, I tried doing both tasks in the same line and completely forgot about that. Dumb mistake. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [sed has more commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands) than just `s///`. To insert a line at the top of a file:

```
sed -e '1i\
\\\documentstyle[11pt]{article}' -e 's/[0-9]//g' file
```

(frustratingly, the number of backslashes to achieve a backslash in the output was found by trial and error)

The bonus is that does not affect your goal to remove numbers.

Answer (score 0):

My second command was removing numbers, working as intended indeed, but I was just trying to do it all at once. Credits to Jonathan Leffler.